# Recognize self written text

Tags: ios, swift

is there any lib which could be used to recognize self written text (like taking a photo of a piece of paper)?
I have already searched on google but i have found nothing.
I hope somebody can tell me something.

Answer (score 1):

I just did a quick google search so I don't know if this will fully satisfy your needs but it is a full OCR library made for iOS 7+. If this library in specific doesn't work then you'll want to research other OCR (optical character recognition) libraries.

https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS

EDIT: I should clarify that I mean it will perform the character recognition that you are asking for but without more specifics on your project I can't guarantee it will work for your use case!